# kaminari and Mongoid 3 page doesn't work as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, kaminari, mongoid3

Hi I am trying to use kaminari as a way to page my collection of 19K results however it doesn't seem to be doing what it is saying on the tin?

I have 19293 documents:

```
1.9.3p194 :046 >   Content.count
=> 19293
```

But when I try to get the first page I still get 19293

```
1.9.3p194 :059 >   Content.page(1).per(50).count
=> 19293
```

Any idea what I could be doing wring?

I am using the gem:

```
14:34:58:myapp(master)$ be gem list kaminari
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
kaminari (0.14.1)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this issue](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/1131) on the Mongoid Github repo.

To get the correct entries for the page, do:

```
Content.page(1).per(50).all.to_a
```

This will evaluate the Mongoid criteria, yielding only 50 entries.

Comment: tho Content.page(1).per(50).count(true) gives me error of: NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for true:TrueClass

Comment: Try the second code sample. I'll update my answer and remove the first one.